# Provision Access Policy with DependsOn

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I'm trying to do the following:

- Create a keyvault (works)
- Create an AZ function (works)
- Use the keyvault's vaultURI as an App Setting to the AZ function (works)
- Give the AZ function managed identity (works)
- Create an Access Policy whereby the AZ function has access to the keyvault (whoopsie!)

Originally I was creating the Access Policy within the Keyvault, but I had to declare the AZ function as depending on the Key Vault (such that I could fetch its URI). Obviously, I was then unable to set Key Vault to depend on the AZ Function (since this would create a cyclic dependency). I then tried creating the AccessPolicy as another step, and marking it as depends on the KeyVault, and the AZ Function (thinking it would be provisioned last).

But for some reason, when looking at the deployment logs, it always seems like he's trying to deploy it first! Any help would be appreciated.

ARM Template truncated for brevity:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
      "location": "[ResourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "Standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('userId')]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "Get",
                "List",
                "Update",
                "Create",
                "Import",
                "Delete",
                "Recover",
                "Backup",
                "Restore"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "Get",
                "List",
                "Set",
                "Delete",
                "Recover",
                "Backup",
                "Restore"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "Get",
                "List",
                "Update",
                "Create",
                "Import",
                "Delete",
                "Recover",
                "Backup",
                "Restore",
                "ManageContacts",
                "ManageIssuers",
                "GetIssuers",
                "ListIssuers",
                "SetIssuers",
                "DeleteIssuers"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'),'/add')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      //tried both the above and the below
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
        "[variables('functionName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "Get",
                "Set",
                "Delete"
              ],
              "certificates": [
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('functionName')]",
      "location": "[ResourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('planName')]",
        "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
        "[variables('storageAccName')]",
        "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
        "[variables('databaseName')]"
      ],
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[variables('planName')]",
        "enabled": true,
        "reserved": false
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('functionName')]",
            "[variables('databaseName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('functionName')]",
            "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
            "[variables('storageAccName')]",
            "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
          ],
          "properties": "[union(variables('completeAppSettings'),json(concat('{ AzureWebJobsStorage:\"', concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value), '\", WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING:\"',\tconcat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value), '\", WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE:\"', variables('functionName'), '\", APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY:\"', reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey, '\", KeyVaultUri:\"', reference(concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'))).vaultUri, '\"}')))]"
        },
        {
          "type": "slots",
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "name": "[variables('functionStagingName')]",
          "location": "[ResourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('functionName')]",
            "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
          ],
          "kind": "functionapp",
          "properties": {
            "enabled": false,
            "serverFarmId": "[variables('planName')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

P.s. I know the way I'm creating my app settings is a work of art (sarcasm). Please don't judge me, just know that it works.

P.p.s Complete ARM Template: https://pastebin.com/mma4PyRu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your template is absolutely fine, so if this doesnt work it looks like a bug. having said that, you can always work around this by moving your `accessPolicy` assignment into a nested template:

```
{
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
   "name": "linkedTemplate",
   "dependsOn": [
       "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
       "[variables('functionName')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
       "mode": "Incremental",
       "templateLink": {
       "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json",
       "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "managedIdentityId":{"value": "[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]"}
    }
}
```

You'd need to upload the template somewhere (which should consist of just your `accessPolicy` assignment

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#external-template

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. Yep, I was leaving nested templates as a last resort, but I think i'll have to fall back to them.

Comment: I've seen some bugs with the managed identity thing reference, it seems to just happen when the deployment starts no matter what. if that occurs, you'd need to move the reference function to retrieve the managed identity inside the nested template, then it would work (because it would only start when the nested template starts)

Comment: Tried this using an inline nested template and it didn't work. I then changed the logic such that I wasn't passing the managed identity id as a param, but rather passing the function name and then retrieving the identity inside... still didn't work.   

Figuring out how to get it to work using a linked template (since i have to upload it somewhere) will take bit of reading, since this is part of a DevOps CICD pipeline.   

Honestly, the easy fix is to simply run the template twice. It will fail the first time, but work the second. It's a poopy way, but it's a way.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the apiVersion from the reference() function, that should delay the call until after the resource is provisioned.  e.g.

```
[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default')).principalId]"
```

Comment: Unfortunately my situation has not improved. Arguably has gotten worse now actually! Error message: Message=Deployment template validation failed:
'The resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/REDACTEDFORPRIVACY/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default' is
not defined in the template.

Comment: Ok, would have to see your entire deployment...  If the resource is deployed in a separate template, then you must provide the apiVersion.  But in that case, the eval of the function should be delayed until the deployment.  If it's in the same template, then you don't need the apiVersion which also has the same effect of delaying the deployment.  You can post here or email me directly if that's better - bmoore at microsoft

Comment: Very grateful for the help, but that won't be necessary. I opted to make use of nested templates. Your comment on the apiVersion is good to know though! Thanks